# Final clean up in specs2

Tags: scala, specs2

I am writing a specs2 Unittest for my scala software. The execution is working well. The only problem I have, is that I need to clean up after all test are finished. I just cannot find any solution for that. Is there a way to execute some functions after all test are finished?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a [Step](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Steps/Actions) at the end of your specification:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._

class MySpec extends Specification {

  // lots of examples here

  // cleanup there
  step(cleanUp())
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that if any step throws an exception then not running cleanUp?

Comment: Yes but that will fail the run.

Comment: This will fail the run, but will not kill your server that was started in the beginning of the test

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use After `with After` and implement `def after` function.

Example:

```
class Context extends Specification {
....
}

trait trees extends mutable.After {
  def after = cleanupDB
}
```

Comment: Does this work for the specification? As in: class Spec extends Specification with After { ... }

Comment: *After* runs after each test, but the OQ referred to cleanup after *all* tests.